# Combinatorial Proof About number of possible resamplings of cases

Tags: combinatorics

Consider $n$ distinct
observations $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, and consider a bootstrap that resamples
cases with replacement and generates $n$ bootstrapped observations. I want
to find the number of possible ways I can bootstrap a set of observations
using this procedure. My friend recommended that I can consider distributing
$n$ items into $n$ boxes, i.e. the number of ways I can assign the
bootstrapped observations $X_1^*,\ldots,X_n^*$ to the actual observations
$X_1,\ldots,X_n$, where bootstrapped observations are not necessarily distinct.
I would imagine that this proceeds in a case by case procedure, i.e. that
there $n$ ways to assign a given bootstrapped observation to an actual
observation and we do this for each of the $n$ bootstrapped values so we
have initially $\sum_{i=1}^n n = n^2$ ways. We then we must remove instances
where we have bootstrapped values that take on the same actual values, i.e.
$\exists i \neq j. X_i^{*} = X_j^{*} = X_1$.
The problem is, I am having some difficulty figuring
out how to remove the discussed duplicate instances. Any recommendations on
how to do this?

Comment: The number of options that result when you have $n$ independent choices with $n$ options in each case is not $\sum n=n^2$ but $\prod n=n^n$. I don't understand why you want to remove values. Further up, you said "bootstrapped observations are not necessarily distinct", but it seems now you want to make them distinct after all? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ordering of the $X_1^*,\ldots,X_n^*$ matters, then there are $n^n$ outcomes: each element of the bootstrap sample can be one of the $n$ elements in the original sample. [See joriki's comment.]

---

If the ordering of the $X_1^*,\ldots,X_n^*$ does not matter, then [after computing manually for small $n$] it seems the number comes from [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A001700) $1,3,10,35,\ldots$ where the $n$th term is $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$. We can verify this below.

*Note that your question is basically the following. "How many ways can I write $n$ as an ordered sum of $n$ nonnegative integers?" Here, ordered means $1+3+0+0$ is different than $0+1+0+3$.*

This led me to the notion of [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)), and indeed at the bottom of the Wikipedia page, the formula for the number of compositions of $n$ objects into $k$ parts (here, we have $k=n$) matches the one above.

Directly, the argument is as follows ("stars and bars"): consider $2n$ stars placed in a row. There are $2n-1$ "gaps" between neighboring stars, and we want to place $n-1$ "bars" in some of these gaps (at most one bar per gap).

For example with $n=2$, the possible outcomes are $*|***$ and $**|**$ and $***|*$.

We claim each one of these arrangements corresponds with a bootstrap sample (without ordering). Indeed, we have divided the $2n$ stars into $n$ non-empty groups. If we take the number of stars in each group and subtract $1$ from each, we get a sequence of $n$ non-negative numbers that add up to $n$. This corresponds to the number of times that $X_1$ appears in the bootstrap sample, the number of times $X_2$ appears, and so on.

For example, $*|***$ corresponds to $\{X_2,X_2\}$, and $**|**$ corresponds to $\{X_1,X_2\}$, and $***|*$ corresponds to $\{X_1,X_1\}$.

There are $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ ways to place the $n-1$ bars in the $2n-1$ gaps, which proves our guess above.